# cant connect to windows remote desktop using win10 app, using ipv6

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, ipv6

i used to be able to connect to my home pc from work using ipv4, but i got a new router that gave my home pc an ipv6 address, and since then i can't connect. created port 3389, tried putting [ipv6-address]:3389 into the "PC name" and the gateway input, no luck.

note: my ipv6 address is formatted [xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx]:3389

Comment: What have you done to verify that your home PC's IPv6 address is externally visible?

Comment: Did you open the firewall for the PC's IPv6 address on that port?

Comment: @Scott nothing other than port forwarding with my router.

Comment: @RonMaupin could you walk me through the steps for that?

Comment: You are going to need to give details of the router model, etc.

Comment: There is no such thing as port forwarding with IPv6. You simply open the ports you want in your firewall.

Comment: @RonMaupin i have an xfinity gateway.

Comment: My point is that your system(s) can report (claim to have) IPv6 addresses, but that doesn’t mean that your ISP recognizes them and routes to them.  You should try to ping your home PC from work, or connect to some other service, using IPv6.